# One-page scroll plugin: I don't want the whole page to slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change my website to be one-page scrollable. When the user scrolls, the content changes. I thought I could do that with the [onepage-scroll plugin](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll), but wasn't successful.

**Goal:**

**I'd like to have the menu and a few other elements fixed. I want to change just the content, not slide the whole page up/down as the plugin does.**

[image]

To sum up, I want to trigger animations (block revealing effect etc.) when the user scrolls. I was thinking about making the website one-page scrollable, and when the user scrolls, just redirect it to a new folder with HTML/CSS/JS files (e.g., the menu stays the same, but the content changes). Maybe that would be one possible solution to my problem?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. The site you're referencing isn't using any scroll events. Open the site in Chrome and open developer tools. Then set the view to mobile (or tablet, same thing). If you're in mobile mode in Chrome, your mouse acts like a finger would on a real Smartphone. By that logic your 'swiping' over the screen with your mouse should trigger the scroll event, but it doesn't. Therefor, it isn't actual scrolling that is triggering the fancy animations.

I believe Fleur Moreau used an 'mousewheel' event listener to trigger the animations.

```
var link = document.querySelector('body');
link.addEventListener('mousewheel', function (event) {

    // Prevent the link from updating the URL
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do something...
    console.log('Triggering fancy animations!')

}, false);
```

or if you're using jquery

```
 $('body').on('mousewheel',function(event){

    // Prevent the link from updating the URL
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do something...
    console.log('Triggering fancy animations!')

});
```

Good luck with your project